# How to trim text using PHP

Tags: php, trim

How to trim some word in php? Example like

`pid="5" OR pid="3" OR`

I want to remove the last `OR`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest using [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) to stick together SQL expressions like that. First build an array of simple expressions, then implode them with OR:

```
$pids = array('pid = "5"', 'pid = "3"');

$sql_where = implode(' OR ', $pids);
```

Now `$sql_where` is the string `'pid = "5" OR pid = "3"'`. You don't have to worry about leftover ORs, even when there is only one element in `$pids`.

Also, an entirely different solution is to append `" false"` to your SQL string so it will end in `"... OR false"` which will make it a valid expression.

@RussellDias' answer is the real answer to your question, these are just some alternatives to think about.

Answer (score 7):

You can try [rtrim](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

> rtrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string

```
$string = "pid='5' OR pid='3' OR";
echo rtrim($string, "OR"); //outputs pid='5' OR pid='3'
```

Comment: The author does not state his intentions... and it answers the question clearly.

Comment: at least substr() would be more adequate to the *goal*, not a literal question. Don't blame author. Don't you have your own brains to think with?

Comment: His *goal* is to simply get rid of the last OR. Which this does. If you have a solution then please feel free to post it...

Comment: author's intentions is **clear:** to get rid of **word** "OR", not characters O and R. Your solution is terrible for the programmer.

Comment: Another SO-style answering robot.

Comment: As stated earlier, feel free to post your solution. I do not wish to waste my time with petty arguments about 'my brains'.

Comment: yeah, there is nothing to argue

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Having a bad day?

Comment: using rtrim() is fine here, a bit clever (and probably influenced by the wording of the question), and shows the statement's purpose a lot more clearly than substr() would. We're <b>trim</b>ming the word <b>"OR"</b> off of the <b>r</b>ight end of the <b>$string</b>. It does look like rtrim() is working at the word level rather than the char level (I didn't even realize this until Col Shrapnel finally spelled it out), but I think in this case, where you know your string will always end in " OR", it's a great way to trim it off.

Comment: jeremy, you only know that now. There's no guarantee that a maintainer a few years down the road notice this hack. A clear, self-contained solution without quirks or side-issues is often best for maintainability. Your own solution is an example of an excellent solution, where it's easy to add more arguments to the query without breaking anything. rtrim() is not that excellent, because it does have quirks and non-obvious side effects.

Comment: I agree with Jeremy's solution as it provides the maintainability element, which mine lacks. I would rather get an explanation as to why mine is bad (thanks for that Emil) rather than just negative criticism.

Comment: rtrim() will remove 'OR' from the end, but it will also remove 'RO', or just 'R' or just 'O', if that is what the string happens to end with. It might not be the most robust solution, but it works, and I don't think it is quite as evil as it has been made out to be.

Answer (score 4):

Using [substr](http://php.net/substr) to find and remove the ending `OR`:

```
$string = "pid='5' OR pid='3' OR";
if(substr($string, -3) == ' OR') {
  $string = substr($string, 0, -3);
}
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression would also work:

```
$str = 'pid="5" OR pid="3" OR';
print preg_replace('/\sOR$/', '', $str);
```

Comment: While it would work, it's more complicated and computationally expensive than necessary

Comment: @bemance: I can't argue with that.  A quick test of 1 million repetitions on my PC shows: `preg_replace` 2428ms, `rtrim` 624ms, `substr` 604ms, `implode` 660ms - `preg_replace` is approximately 4 times slower than the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this?

```
$str='pid="5" OR pid="3" OR';    
$new_str=substr($str,0, strlen($str)-3);
```