# Php how to remove any last commas

Tags: php, trim

Example output

```
1. test,test,test,test,test,
2. test,test,test,,
3. test,test,,,
4. test,,,,,
```

I tried use implode according to my [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074665/how-to-trim-text-using-php/3074690#3074690) but It's trim only last comma.

How to remove any last commas?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
rtrim('test,,,,,', ',');
```

See [the manual](http://php.net/rtrim).

Answer (score 35):

[rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) for example:

```
$str = 'foo,bar,blah,bleh,';
echo rtrim($str,',');

// foo,bar,blah,bleh
```

Answer (score 8):

completely different way:

```
$str = "1,2,3,4,";
$str = substr($str,0,strlen($str)-1);
```

Comment: Old topic but should be noted. Although this would remove the last comma, it would only remove one comma. If the comma was missing it would remove the 4 in this example.

Comment: Also very impractical, since it would remove not only the comma, but other characters too. For example, if we had the `$str = "1,2,3,4"`, it would remove `4`, causing us to end up with `$str = "1,2,3,"`

Comment: "Also very impractical" - that's too polite. It should be noted this "solution" is terrible and could lead to data loss. DO NOT USE.