# Remove comma after last word

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

This is an array of wordpress tags.

There's a comma after each word.

How to easily remove comma from the last word of an array?

```
<?php
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
  foreach($posttags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->name . ', '; 
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120398/php-how-to-remove-any-last-commas

Comment: why don't you use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) instead?

Comment: Thank you guys. Works great.