# get rid of last comma in a loop in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to send mulitple sms and the correct format for the api to send the text messages should be `(00,001,002)` but with my current sql it produces this results `(00,001,002,)`

How can i correct my script to get this results `(00,001,002)`

```
$query_rs_p = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY id DESC";
$rs_p = mysql_query($query_rs_p, $insurance) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_p = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_p);
$totalRows_rs_p = mysql_num_rows($rs_p);
$ph=',';
do {
echo $row_rs_p['phone_number'].$ph;
} while ($row_rs_p = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_p));
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120398/php-how-to-remove-any-last-commas

Comment: `while(...) { $arr[] = $row['number']; } echo implode(',' $arr)` as an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of echoing it out in your loop, put it all in a string. Then trim off the last comma before you output it:

```
$query_rs_p = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY id DESC";
$rs_p = mysql_query($query_rs_p, $insurance) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_p = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_p);
$totalRows_rs_p = mysql_num_rows($rs_p);
$ph=',';
$string = '';
do {
$string .= $row_rs_p['phone_number'].$ph;
} while ($row_rs_p = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_p));
$string = rtrim($string, ',');
echo $string;
```

Or, better yet, just build this string in your query. Much simpler and cleaner:

```
$query_rs_p = "SELECT group_concat(phone_number) as phine_numbers FROM contacts ORDER BY id DESC";
$rs_p = mysql_query($query_rs_p, $insurance) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_p = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_p);
echo $row['phone_numbers'];
```

Comment: you answer work but check the spelling of the trin and change to trim

Comment: @neiza You can also edit :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `rtrim` function

```
$rowsphone =  $row_rs_p['phone_number'].$ph;
rtrim($rowsphone,',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most direct would be to just do something like this:

```
$output = '';
do {
    if ($output != '')
        $output .= ',';
    $output .= $row_rs_p['phone_number'];
while ($row_rs_p = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_p);

echo $output;
```